# Keyboard disappeared after updating HTC Desire X software to 4.1

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard, htc-desire-x

I updated my HTC Desire X software to 4.1 and restarted my phone. When my phone turned on again, I tried using the search bar but there was no keyboard. So I thought I'd search the internet using my phone to see why my keyboard hadn't come up before, but even when I clicked on the search bar on Chrome, the keyboard still didn't come up. I then went onto my text messages and tried typing there but still no keyboard. I tried looking through the phone's settings and didn't find anything there.

Has this ever happened to anyone else? If so, how did you get your keyboard back?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if there's anything set in `Settings > Language & Keyboard`?

Let me know if it works.

Comment: In my settings there is no 'Language and Input' instead it says 'language and keyboard' and then gives me a list of options which are system language, HTC Sense Input and then speech voice search. There is no Keyboard and input methods option here.

Comment: Yes I can see them and I've tried going through them but they're just you're usual settings. It doesn't give any thing else really so I don't think it has something to do with the settings but the phone itself.

Comment: @Creme224 How about if you unset the keyboard, and set it again?